# I can't add contacts using expo react native, "WRITE_CONTACTS" permission is required but I already have it

Tags: react-native, expo

This is my `app.json`

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "add-contact-list",
    "slug": "add-contact-list",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "android": {
      "package": "the.contacts.adder"
    }
  },
  "android": {
    "permissions": [
      "WRITE_CONTACTS"
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see I already have the permission, in my code I also ask the permission to the user

```
 const { status } = await Contacts.requestPermissionsAsync();
 if (status === 'granted') {
    await Contacts.addContactAsync(newContact);
 }
```

But I get the following error when I try to add the contact:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Missing write contacts permission.]
```

What I'm doing wrong? I'm testing my app on android

I'm using only 1 component which is the main component, here is the full source code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import * as Contacts from 'expo-contacts';


export default function App() {
    const start = async (params) => {
        const { status } = await Contacts.requestPermissionsAsync();
        if (status === 'granted') {
            const newContact = {
              [Contacts.Fields.Name]: `Test`,
              [Contacts.Fields.PhoneNumbers]: [
                {
                    number: '(81) 8184-2218',
                    isPrimary: true,
                    digits: `81842218`,
                    countryCode: '+52',
                    id: `XXXX-TEST`,
                    label: `TEST`,
                },
              ]
            };

            await Contacts.addContactAsync(newContact);
        }
    }


    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Click the button to save the phone number</Text>
      
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={start}
          style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, color: '#fff' }}>Click here</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  button: {
    width: 120,
    height: 57,
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    textAlign: 'center'
  }
});
```

**Update**
I also generate an standalone app but it also didn't work to solve my problem.

I don't know if I also need to edit `AndroidManifest.xml`, I have checked this file and the permission is not registered there, but because I'm using expo to build the app, I guess is not necessary to edit native platform source code.

Comment: we need to see the code, are you using it inside `useEffect` ?? which library you are using

Comment: I have updated the question and posted the full source code. thank you

Comment: try to add this `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />` in AndroidManifest.xml and see if it works

Comment: I have already added it, but I'm getting the same error :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to add `READ_CONTACTS` Android Permission in your `app.json`.

`READ_CONTACTS`: Allows an application to read the user's contacts data.

`WRITE_CONTACTS`: Allows an application to write the user's contacts data.

```json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "add-contact-list",
    "slug": "add-contact-list",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "android": {
      "package": "the.contacts.adder"
    }
  },
  "android": {
    "permissions": [
      "READ_CONTACTS",
      "WRITE_CONTACTS"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the documentation: [Permissions](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/contacts/#permissions)

Answer (score 0):

app.json must be have this permission:

```
 "android": {
    ...
      "permissions": [
        ...
        "android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"
      ]
    },
```